# Cannot open file "rgnlstng.xml" for reading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Software details:

Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit
  Sharepoint Server 2007 w/SP2
  WSS 3 w/SP2

---

NOTE: Previously some one had install sharepoint server 2010 on our server and I'm re-installing the original software to get things back in order.

---

I'm running the following command line and getting the error in the title of this thread in the log file:

```
 stsadm -o spsearch -action start -farmserviceaccount myDomain\servicetfs01 -farmservicepassword myPassword -farmcontentaccessaccount servicetfs01readonly -farmcontentaccesspassword myPassword -databaseserver tfs01 -databasename WSS_Search_TFS01 -sqlauthlogin sa -sqlauthpassword myPassword
```

I ran the command line as administrator and still I get this error. If I try to accomplish the same thing through the central administration web page I get the same exact error.

If found rgnlstng.xml in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\XML however I used sysinternals process monitor and found that stsadmin trying to read the file from **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Template\0\xml\rgnlstng.xml** which doesn't exist.

Is there a registry key that is fubared? Any ideas how to solve this?

Here is the log that is generated when I run the command:

```
Initializing the configuration database connection.      
Creating database OM object with the following settings: Server = 'tfs01', Name = 'WSS_Search_TFS01', Username = 'sa', Integrated security = 'Off'.  
Updating SPPersistedObject SPServer Name=tfs01 Parent=SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config_2007. Version: -1 Ensure: 1, HashCode: 54267293, Id: 41399c43-d2b8-4017-a8e6-8d907a2b1d9d, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update(Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedChildCollection`1.Add(T newObj, Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedChildCollection`1.Ensure(T newObj)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchDatabase.Create(String databaseServer, String databaseName, String databaseUsername, String databasePassword)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administra...  
...tion.CommandLine.SPSearch.Execute()     at Microsoft.Search.Administration.CommandLine.CommandBase.Run(String command, StringDictionary keyValues, String& output)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.RunOperation(SPGlobalAdmin globalAdmin, String strOperation, StringDictionary keyValues, SPParamCollection pars)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.Main(String[] args)       
Updating SPPersistedObject SPDatabaseServiceInstance Parent=SPServer Name=TFS01. Version: -1 Ensure: 1, HashCode: 33476626, Id: adb31063-52a6-4e27-9d9b-c8eaccfaeacd, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstance.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update(Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedChildCollection`1.Add(T newObj, Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedChildCollection`1.Ensure(T newObj)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchDatabase.Create(String databaseServer, String databaseName, String databaseUsername, String databasePassword)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administra...  
...tion.CommandLine.SPSearch.Execute()     at Microsoft.Search.Administration.CommandLine.CommandBase.Run(String command, StringDictionary keyValues, String& output)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.RunOperation(SPGlobalAdmin globalAdmin, String strOperation, StringDictionary keyValues, SPParamCollection pars)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.Main(String[] args)       
Creating database OM object with SQL auth for database 'WSS_Search_TFS01'.   
Windows SharePoint Services log file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Primary Domain = AMERICAS, Computer Name = TFS01     
#20001: Cannot open file "rgnlstng.xml" for reading.     
(#3: Cannot open file "rgnlstng.xml" for reading.)   
Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.  
Now terminating ULS (STSADM.EXE, onetnative.dll)     
In SSOService::Synch(), sso database conn string:
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind. Been working on this all day and minutes after posting this I figured it out. We had tons of errors initially trying to re-install the products and a lot of them had to do with missing registry keys and mainly sharepoint 2010 assemblies and policies in the GAC taking precedence over the older 2007 assemblies. Somewhere along the line we added numerous ServerLanguage keys and strings values to the registry to get the initial installs going. We couldn't figure out exactly were the ServerLanguage key was supposed to go so we just made a lot of them to cover all the basis and ultimately this came back to bite me.

One of the registry keys was causing this issue and after deleting it the command now succeeds! hooray beer!

[image]